# Remove element in array by its index - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model that looks like this:

```
 Member: {
  memberId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  customPlaylists: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
  }
       
         }
```

customPlaylist's array holds object that look like this:

```
{ name: 'playlist name', urls: [] } // urls array contains url strings
```

Is there a way using mongoose's updateOne method to remove a url from the urls array by its index in the array? (I use the member's ID in the filter object)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a straight (1 query) way to do this. But you can try this

```
<collectionName>.update({}, {$unset : {"urls.<indexNumberHere>" : 1 }}) 
<collectionName>.update({}, {$pull : {"urls" : null}})
```

There was a ticket to [implement this feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1014) and the resolution was `Won't Do`

Comment: there were some single query ones in the link

Comment: Each element in customPlaylists is an object with a 'name' and 'urls' property. How can I target the urls property in an object whose 'name' is 'X'?